# inserting sentences between subequations

Tags: equations, amsmath, align

My apologies for asking so many questions here. I want to introduce a sentence in between 2 subequations which is not in math mode. Here is the code that I am using:

```
   \documentclass[12pt,oneside,reqno]{amsart}
   \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{subequations}
      \begin{align}
       x=1222222222222222\\
       Here x is an arbitrary constant\\
       y=2
      \end{align}
    \end{subequations}
    \end{document}​
```

In the output, the line `Here x is an arbitrary constant` appears in math mode. Also `y=2` is aligned towards the right which is something I don't want. Is it possible to include the sentence inside the subequations not in math mode. Also how do I align `y=2` along with `x` in the center?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A look through the `amsmath` manual (`texdoc amsmath`) will be beneficial. The `intertext` command may be what you're after, alignment points are specified with `&`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}
  \begin{align}
   x&=1222222222222222\\
 \intertext{Here $x$ is an arbitrary constant}
   y&=2
  \end{align}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}​
```

[image]

Comment: A quick follow-up note to the OP: in order for the `\intertext` command to work, you needn't be in the `align` environment; for instance, the `gather` environment, which (unsurprisingly) does *not* align the equations on some point, will also work.

Answer (score 6):

As Torbjørn pointed out, the `\intertext`-command from `amsmath` allows to add normal text within an `align`-environment (or similar) while keeping the alignement points.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  a &= b \\
  c &= d
\intertext{Some text}
  e &= f
\end{align}
```

[image: intertext from amsmath]

It should be mentioned, however, that *Morten Hoegholm*'s package `mathtools` (which provides several corrections for and additions to `amsmath`), corrects a slight problem of `\intertext` and provides a new command `\shortintertext` with less spacing.

```
\begin{align}
  a &= b \\
  c &= d
\shortintertext{Some text}
  e &= f
\end{align}
```

[image: shortintertext from mathtools]

In addition to this, there are options to fine-tune spacing.

```
% (This works, in contrast to what can be found in the current version of the manual.)
\mathtoolsset{
  aboveshortintertextdim=20pt, % (default: 3pt)
  belowshortintertextdim=10pt, % (default: 3pt)
} 

\begin{align}
  a &= b \\
  c &= d
\shortintertext{Some text with excessive spacing}
  e &= f
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image: shortintertext with adjusted spacing]