# How do I put annotations within my gather block?

Tags: math-mode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [inserting sentences between subequations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32756/inserting-sentences-between-subequations)

I am proving a math theory in a gather block. I would like to annotate my proof. For instance,

```
\begin{gather}
... \\
By the inductive step,
... \\
\end{gather}
```

However, when I do so, the text meshes together in the generated pdf.

How do I put annotations within my gather block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\intertext` from `amsmath`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
a = b \\
\intertext{By the inductive step,}
c = d
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

The [mathtools](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package offers you `\shortintertext` with reduced vertical spacing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
a = b \\
\shortintertext{By the inductive step,}
c = d
\end{gather}

\begin{gather}
a = b \\
\intertext{By the inductive step,}
c = d
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image]