# How do I left and right justify text within an align environment

Tags: environments, align

I want to simultaneously have text left and right justified around an align environment.  I'm able to do this, but my solution seems like a dreadful hack.  I really don't want to prepend every line with `&&`.  But `&&` doesn't really get the text to be flush with the left.  Does anyone have a better solution?

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,mathtools}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
Establish the following identity:
    \[\cos^4\theta-\sin^4\theta=\cos(2\theta)\]
\begin{align*}%'
    \tag*{\makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace*{-\textwidth}\textbf{Proof:}}}
    \cos^4\theta-\sin^4\theta 
    &=     (1-\sin^2\theta)^2 - \sin^4\theta
    && \text{Use $\cos^2\theta=1-\sin^2\theta$}
    \\
    &    =    1 - 2\sin^2\theta + \sin^4\theta - \sin^4\theta
    \\
    &    =    1 - 2\sin^2\theta = \cos(2\theta) && \text{Double angle formula.}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! Note that if you indent your code by 4 spaces, it will be displayed as a code block. Alternatively, you can select the code and click the "code" (`{}`) button.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What is preventing you from writing "Proof" outside the `align*` environment? Having it on the same height as the first formula is not at all needed or desirable, in my opinion.

Comment: It's just an example.  It's not the best example.  I agree with your comment about "proof".  The point is that this example achieves the effect I desire.  I'm interested in a better way of achieving the effect.

Comment: Left-aligned text "inside" `align*` is achieved using `\intertext`. See [inserting sentences between subequations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32756/5764).

Comment: The problem with intertext is that it places the text between the lines.  I want the text on the same line.

Comment: `flalign*` really flushes left and right, but it still needs `&&` *hacks*, as you said.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As one of the comments mentioned, I would use the not well-known `flalign` or `flalign*` environment, like in this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{flalign}
\text{Proof}    && a &= b &&\\
    && a &= b &&\\
    && a &= b && \text{some comment}\\
    && a &= b &&
\end{flalign}

\begin{flalign*}
\text{Proof}    && a &= b &&\\
    && a &= b &&\\
    && a &= b && \text{some comment}\\
    && a &= b &&
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

This will result in:

[image]

Comment: Is the only difference between the * and non-star versions the numbering?

Comment: @soandos: As far as I know: Yes.