# How to align over multiple lines?

Tags: formatting, align, amsmath

So I have some lines of formulas that I want to align:

```
\Xi_c=(0.136,\ 0.307,\ 0.057^+\ ||\ 0.194^-,\ 0.148,\ 0. 087, 0.074)\ \text{  and  }\
\aleph_c=[\varnothing].
```

and

```
\Xi_c=(0.136,\ 0.307,\ 0^+\ ||\ 0.137^-,\ 0.148,\ 0. 087, 0.074)\ \text{  and  }\
\aleph_c=\bigl[\stackrel{0.057}{(CC)}\bigr].
```

I would like to align these at the double bars `||`, but I have to write some lines of text between the formulas, so I can't put them in them same `align` environment.

How can I align these formula while still having a lot of text (some paragraphs) between them?

The code, to explain my problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\[ \Xi_c=(0.136,\ 0.307,\ 0.057^+\ ||\ 0.194^-,\ 0.148,\ 0. 087, 0.074)\ \text{  and  }\ \aleph_c=[\varnothing]. \]
A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. 
\[  \Xi_c=(0.136,\ 0.307,\ 0^+\ ||\ 0.137^-,\ 0.148,\ 0. 087, 0.074)\ \text{  and  }\ \aleph_c=\bigl[\stackrel{0.057}{(CC)}\bigr]. \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Like I said, I can't use `align`, since that only works if the two formulas are in the same environment. Since I have to add a lot of text inbetween them, the two formulas are going to be in seperate `align` environments.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I obviously didn't look very carefully. Can you use `\intertext`? See e.g. [inserting sentences between subequations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32760) or [How can I break an align environment for a paragraph?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9577)

Comment: You might be able to figure out the lengths of the two expressions before the `||` and use a box with the larger length. But are you sure you have to? The equations are very far apart, so the alignment can't convey much information to the reader. If you align them as you wish in your example the second equation won't fit on one line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily do it with `align*` and `\intertext`, but the result shows that you shouldn't: the apparent misalignment will look very odd to your readers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\Xi_c=(0.136,\ 0.307,\ 0.057^+\ &||\ 0.194^-,\ 0.148,\ 0. 087, 0.074)
  \ \text{  and  }\ \aleph_c=[\varnothing].
\\
\intertext{A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of 
text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A 
lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes 
here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text 
goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of 
text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A 
lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes 
here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text 
goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of 
text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A 
lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes 
here.}
\Xi_c=(0.136,\ 0.307,\ 0^+\ &||\ 0.137^-,\ 0.148,\ 0. 087, 0.074)
  \ \text{  and  }\ \aleph_c=\bigl[\overset{0.057}{(CC)}\bigr].
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I see that it looks weird, but in the eventual document it will look better. I can't explain why here without posting the entire page, but there's a reason I specifically need to align them at the `||`.